# Chrome extension losing requested permissions after browser restart

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, accesscontrolexception

I developed a chrome extension which communicates with IP phones.

The communication is done in a event page which is sending POST requests via the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Because the hostname or IP address of the phone is configured in the options page I added `optional_permissions` to the manifest file and request them from the user after saving the options with `chrome.permissions.request`.

Cross-Origin XHR works now without any problems until I restart chrome...

After restarting chrome it seems like the requested permission is lost and I get the typical 
 `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

When I click on the extensions permissions I can also see that my requested permission is no longer listed.

Because the `chrome.permissions.request` is only working for a user gesture I can't request it during the load of my extension or on the fly. If I request the permission again in my options page I don't get asked again whether I want to allow it or not put the permission is granted and everything works again as usual.

Is there a way to get this permission granted persistent after requesting it? I only want the extension to have access to the endpoints it needs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I have not yet experienced problems with the optional permission API in Chrome. Are you certain that you didn't revoke the permissions anywhere else?

Comment: I can't think of how I could possibly have revoked it. There is no call to `chrome.permissions.remove` in my code so far. The line in my manifest file look like this: `"optional_permissions": ["*://*/CGI/Execute"]` and my request looks like this: `chrome.permissions.request({origins: ['http://' + phoneAdress + '/CGI/Execute']}, ...`

Comment: I guess that the problem is solved when you request `*://*/CGI/Execute` instead of a subset of the declared optional permissions.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems that chrome is not dropping it after a restart but this will add the permission to get access to all data on all websites which I actually wanted to prevent... Is there any other way to do this without having to give the extension this many permissions?

Comment: Explicitly list all permissions you want to request in the manifest file. You could also file a bug at http://crbug.com/new if you want it to be fixed.

Comment: Looks like I have to fill a bug in that case because I can't list the permission in the first place. The user chooses the address of his phone and then the permission needs to be requested cause I don't know his address in the first place. Requesting only a private subnet doesn't work either cause of the way how the wildcards work.

Comment: Your issue sounds like the bug report "[Content scripts' cross-site XHR get banned with optional permissions obtained after restarts.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122527)" which is a duplicate of "[Optional permissions barely working](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123250)". That is marked fixed; however, you may be observing a regression, or perhaps your bug is slightly different from those.

Comment: Looks like there is one difference between the reports and my issue: They used wildcards but requested the exact permission as declared in `optional_permissions`. Which works for me but requests to much permissions. I'm declaring `*://*/CGI/Execute` and I'm requesting `http://192.168.178.41/CGI/Execute` for example. Cause I don't know the hostname or address beforehand. The user defines it. But the issue is similar.

Comment: I just found a matching [Issue 158004](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158004) which is marked as _Fixed_. But it looks like it hasn't been committed to the current chrome release yet. I installed the _Dev_ version of chrome but there I still get the error. How do I find out which revision is included in which chrome version? I can see a commit [Revision 182287](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=182287&view=revision) to the VCS but how do I find out if and where it got included? Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the following reported issue answered my question:
[Issue 158004: chrome.permissions.request support for user-supplied URL](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158004).

To make it clear: It is not possible to request a subset of the permissions defined in `optional_permissions`. If you define `http://*/*` then you need to request exactly this string! A subset like `http://example.org/*` wont work!

Here is a quote from a comment in the issue description which makes that clear:
*"There's no wildcard handling, just plain string comparison between the URLPatterns"*

The Issue has been fixed in [Revision 182287](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=182287&view=revision)

The only thing left is to cross your fingers that this fix gets included in a upcomming chrome release soon. We'll have to use the bloody `Access your data on all websites` permission in the meanwhile.

Comment: have you managed to get it working the intended way using `http://*/` / `https://*/` optional permissions? It seems like they still get reset on chrome 36.

Comment: No so far it seems to be the same problem. I checked it again but same behavior as before.

Comment: This feature is available now. From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions): `If you want to request hosts that you only discover at runtime, include "http://*/" and/or "https://*/" as an optional_permission. This lets you specify any origin in Permissions.origins as long as it has a matching scheme.`